# lxml confused by empty xmlns in XSD (XML schema)

Tags: xsd, lxml, xsd-validation

I have an XSD file that includes an inner type and then a reference back to it from an outer type. At the top level, it also includes an empty `xmlns` attribute. Like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema id="foo" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="inner">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="a" type="xs:double" minOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element name="b" type="xs:double" minOccurs="1" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="outer">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="inner" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        <xs:element name="c" type="xs:double" minOccurs="1" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

However if I try to validate some XML against it with the [`lxml` library](https://lxml.de/validation.html):

```
from io import StringIO
from lxml import etree
schema = etree.XMLSchema(file=StringIO(xsd))
xml = "<outer> <inner><a>1</a><b>2</b></inner> <c>3</c> </outer>"
print(schema.validate(etree.parse(StringIO(xml))))
```

Then I get a strange error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 57, in <module>
    schema = etree.XMLSchema(file=StringIO(xsd))
  File "src\lxml\xmlschema.pxi", line 88, in lxml.etree.XMLSchema.__init__
lxml.etree.XMLSchemaParseError: Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'ref': References from this schema to components in the namespace '' are not allowed, since not indicated by an import statement., line 14
```

If I remove the `xmlns=""` part then the error goes away, so that seems to be the problematic part. I don't know too much about namespaces in XML/XSD, but from reading other StackOverflow answers it seems likely that this part is there due to the XSD being generated from C#.

Presumably the original author of the XSD (or the code that generates it) doesn't have this problem when validating XML against it in C#. And I've also managed to validate against it in Python using the [`xmlschema` library](https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - I didn't do anything special, it just seemed to work by default. So it seems to just be `lxml` that doesn't like it.

I don't want to modify the XSD files - as mentioned above, they come from another source, and in fact there are quite a lot of them, so it would be a maintenance burden if they were to change in future. Why is lxml having a problem with it? Is there a way to fix / avoid the error (without modifying the XSD)?

Comment: This seems a bug or quirk in libxml, the library used by lxml. I get a similar error message trying to use `xmllint` e.g. "Schemas parser error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}element', attribute 'ref': References from this schema to components in the namespace '' are not allowed, since not indicated by an import statement.". So basically the `xmlns=""` seems to have the schema parser think any `ref` attribute names are not in no namespace, as the schema has no target namespace and no namespace declared, but in the namespace with the empty string.

Comment: Technically the `xmlns=""` should make no difference, I think, but it seems libxml can't handle it. I don't know of a workaround.

Comment: Basically, https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#defaulting says "The attribute value in a default namespace declaration MAY be empty. This has the same effect, within the scope of the declaration, of there being no default namespace". Either that was clarified before libxml was implemented or the implementation fails to implement that rule.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks a lot for that. If you copy and paste into an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: I've posted a bug to the issue tracker for libxml: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/issues/303

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test but the bug in libxml had been marked fixed!

Comment: Your sample Python code runs fine for me with Python 3.10.6 and lxml 4.9.2.

Comment: Thanks Martin! I'll mention on the bug report